# Can I automate to create android app to firebase project?

Tags: android, firebase

My application has many flavor that has different application id. I want to register these applications to create to Firebase project.
I want to automate below process:

- Create android application in Firebase project.
- Enable crashlytics for the applitaion.
- Download google-service.json of the project.

[Firebase Management API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest) seems to be able to first one, but other can't. I try using puppeteer to control Firebase console in browser, but google prevent to log in by automated browser.

Is there any other solution?

Comment: Did you find solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To download google-services.json, you can call [projects.androidApps.getConfig](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.androidApps/getConfig) from the management API.

For the second one, it's currently not possible.  [Contact Firebase support to file a feature request](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).